# Oracle Cumulative or Incremental subtraction

Tags: oracle, group-by, cumulative-sum

My Table structure & data-

```
CREATE TABLE T_PTS_TEST
   (
        CITY_ID NUMBER,
        MNTH DATE,
        EARNS NUMBER,
        BURNS NUMBER        
   );
   
insert into T_PTS_TEST values( 125600, TO_DATE('2023-May-31', 'YYYY-Month-DD'), 600, -400 );
insert into T_PTS_TEST values( 125600, TO_DATE('2023-June-30', 'YYYY-Month-DD'), 400, -300 );
insert into T_PTS_TEST values( 125600, TO_DATE('2023-July-31', 'YYYY-Month-DD'), 800, -600 );
insert into T_PTS_TEST values( 125600, TO_DATE('2023-August-31', 'YYYY-Month-DD'), 500, 0 );
insert into T_PTS_TEST values( 125600, TO_DATE('2023-September-30', 'YYYY-Month-DD'), 900, 0 );
```

The table-

| CITY_ID | MNTH | EARNS | BURNS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125600 | 31-MAY-23 | 600 | -400 |
| 125600 | 30-JUN-23 | 400 | -300 |
| 125600 | 31-JUL-23 | 800 | -600 |
| 125600 | 31-AUG-23 | 500 | 0 |
| 125600 | 30-SEP-23 | 900 | 0 |

So, the Total burns for this particular city from May to September is -1300 i.e

`select city_id, sum(burns) from T_PTS_TEST group by city_id`

I want to have a cumulative subtraction of this total_burns from each earns as follows-

```
Total Deductions = -1300

Cumulative Deductions
May  -  600 -1300 = -700
June -  400 -700  = -300
July -  800 -300  = 500
Aug  -  500
Sep  -  900
```

The query output should look like-

| CITY_ID | MNTH | EARNS | NET_PTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125600 | 31-MAY-23 | 600 | -700 |
| 125600 | 30-JUN-23 | 400 | -300 |
| 125600 | 31-JUL-23 | 800 | 500 |
| 125600 | 31-AUG-23 | 500 | 500 |
| 125600 | 30-SEP-23 | 900 | 900 |

I can achieve the above by looping inside a PL/SQL block or Function, but how can I do the same using select statements?
I tried using different ways like  `sum(..) over`  and  `lag`. But unable to achieve it.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` analytic function to find the cumulative earns-per-month and the total burns and then use the `LEAST` function to find the lesser of the total and the current month's earns:

```sql
SELECT city_id,
       mnth,
       earns,
       LEAST(
         SUM(earns) OVER (PARTITION BY city_id ORDER BY mnth)
         + SUM(burns) OVER (),
         earns
       ) AS total
FROM   t_pts_test t
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| CITY_ID | MNTH | EARNS | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125600 | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 | 600 | -700 |
| 125600 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | 400 | -300 |
| 125600 | 2023-07-31 00:00:00 | 800 | 500 |
| 125600 | 2023-08-31 00:00:00 | 500 | 500 |
| 125600 | 2023-09-30 00:00:00 | 900 | 900 |

---

You could also use a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT city_id, mnth, earns, total
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city_id ORDER BY mnth) AS rn
  FROM   t_pts_test t
)
MODEL
  PARTITION BY ( city_id )
  DIMENSION BY ( rn )
  MEASURES     ( mnth, earns, burns, 0 AS total )
  RULES (
    total[1]    = earns[1] + Sum(burns)[rn],
    total[rn>1] = LEAST(total[CV()-1], 0) + earns[CV()]
  )
```

(But I'm not sure that after numbering the rows and then performing the `SUM` in the first row of each partition that it may be less efficient when compared to using the first query with just analytic functions; you could profile both solutions and check.)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bL9krHaO)

Comment: This works great @MTO. 
One doubt. We can see that, the Total Deductions of -1300 is completely consumed once it touches the 3rd row. Is it possible to modify your query so that the LEAST & SUM part doesn't execute after the 3rd row i.e when the deductions are finished? By adding some CASE statement or something similar? This would help in optimizing this query further, making sure LEAST(SUM....) is not always executed.

Comment: @satyaprakashPanigrahi No, because the query has no way of knowing when the total deductions will run out.

Comment: Thanks @MTO. What you say makes sense, so I will work on the query provided by you. Still, by any chance, if we can optimize it further with the use of sub-queries, lag, etc...please let me know. Because actual DB could have millions of records, so doing the sum for all the rows could be expensive.

Comment: @satyaprakashPanigrahi You need to find the sum over all the rows to find the total deductions. Performing a cumulative total of the earnings is probably not particularly more expensive.

Comment: Thanks @MTO for the model clause query. Will analyze both & decide on one of them. Have already completed working on the 1st query, the results are fast & the query is very simple. 2nd one looks complicated but will spend some time on that also.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, a bit late though, you could use MODEL clause to get your result:

```sql
Select   CITY_ID, MNTH, EARNS, NET_PTS
From    ( Select  CITY_ID, To_Char(MNTH, 'yyyy-mm') "MNTH", EARNS, BURNS, 
                  0 "NET_PTS"
          From    T_PTS_TEST
        )
  MODEL     Partition By    ( CITY_ID )
            Dimension By    ( MNTH    )
            Measures        ( EARNS, BURNS, NET_PTS )
  RULES   ( NET_PTS[ANY] =   Case When BURNS[CV()] != 0 Then Sum(EARNS)[MNTH <= CV()] + Sum(BURNS)[MNTH Is Not Null] Else EARNS[CV()] End )
```

... OR - if there is a possibility of partial burnes before 0 (as mentioned in MTO's comment) - change the RULES to

```sql
  RULES ( NET_PTS[ANY] =  Case
                          When Nvl(Sum(BURNS)[MNTH Is Not Null] + Sum(EARNS)[MNTH < CV()], Sum(BURNS)[MNTH Is Not Null]) < 0
                          Then ( Nvl(Sum(BURNS)[MNTH Is Not Null] + Sum(EARNS)[MNTH < CV()], Sum(BURNS)[MNTH Is Not Null]) ) + EARNS[CV()]
                          Else EARNS[CV()]
                          End
        )
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
   CITY_ID MNTH         EARNS    NET_PTS
---------- ------- ---------- ----------
    125600 2023-05        600       -700
    125600 2023-06        400       -300
    125600 2023-07        800        500
    125600 2023-08        500        500
    125600 2023-09        900        900
*/
```

Comment: Are you sure on the the `NET_PTS` logic? It works for the OP's data but if the total `burns` exceeds the preceding cumulative `earns` and the current burns is zero then you won't get the correct total. See the final query in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DYYnRvJo).

Comment: @MT0 I'm sure that the logic for the data provided is ok., I'm also sure that it is quite easy to handle the case you mentioned (added it to the answer) and I'm sure that MODEL clause is significantly faster than analytic functions and/or aggregations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation to achieve this:

```
select t.CITY_ID, T_PTS_TEST.MNTH, T_PTS_TEST.EARNS, sum(t2.EARNS) + t.TOTAL as NET_PTS
from T_PTS_TEST
join (
    select CITY_ID, sum(BURNS) as TOTAL
    from T_PTS_TEST
    group by CITY_ID
) t
on T_PTS_TEST.CITY_ID = t.CITY_ID
join (
    select CITY_ID, MNTH, EARNS
    from T_PTS_TEST
    group by CITY_ID, MNTH, EARNS
) t2
on T_PTS_TEST.CITY_ID = t2.CITY_ID and
   T_PTS_TEST.MNTH >= t2.MNTH
group by t.CITY_ID, T_PTS_TEST.MNTH, T_PTS_TEST.EARNS, t.TOTAL
order by t.CITY_ID, T_PTS_TEST.MNTH;
```

Explanation:

- we get the total burns as `t`, grouped by `CITY_ID`, so we do not mix up the cities
- we project `EARNS` "so far" into `t2`
- `t` is joined by `CITY_ID` and `t2` is joined by `CITY_ID` and `MNTH` not being later than the current one
- we `group by` the fields we want to aggregate
- and order by the city and month
- finally, `select` the fields of interest

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0d53/13

EDIT:

Adjusted the query based on the comment-section:

```
select t.CITY_ID, T_PTS_TEST.MNTH, T_PTS_TEST.EARNS, 
case
    when sum(coalesce(t2.EARNS, 0)) < abs(t.TOTAL) then T_PTS_TEST.EARNS + sum(coalesce(t2.EARNS, 0)) + t.TOTAL
    else T_PTS_TEST.EARNS
end as NET_PTS
from T_PTS_TEST
join (
    select CITY_ID, sum(BURNS) as TOTAL
    from T_PTS_TEST
    group by CITY_ID
) t
on T_PTS_TEST.CITY_ID = t.CITY_ID
left join (
    select CITY_ID, MNTH, EARNS
    from T_PTS_TEST
    group by CITY_ID, MNTH, EARNS
) t2
on T_PTS_TEST.CITY_ID = t2.CITY_ID and
   T_PTS_TEST.MNTH > t2.MNTH
group by t.CITY_ID, T_PTS_TEST.MNTH, T_PTS_TEST.EARNS, t.TOTAL
order by t.CITY_ID, T_PTS_TEST.MNTH;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0d53/19

Comment: Hi @Lajos, I'm yet to go through the explanation that you provided, but i executed your query. The output is slightly different from what I want.  The O/P that I'm getting from your query is-                                           
 `NET_PTS 
-700
-300
500
1000
1900`                                                                                                                                            I think some more subtraction has to be done for last 2 rows. Basically, once the Total_Deductions are completely consumed, both  EARNS  &  NET_PTS  should match.

Comment: @satyaprakashPanigrahi thanks for your comment. Adjusted the script in my answer according to the expectation you described here in the comment-section. Thanks!

Comment: @satyaprakashPanigrahi This is going to read from the same table 3 times compared to only once for analytic functions or using a `MODEL` clause. This can be seen in the `EXPLAIN PLAN`s listed in [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/16xX_vMW) where you can look at the number of `TABLE ACCESS FULL` for each plan.